# how to upload file in ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

Uploading file and get the formdata in nodejs server as seen below:

[image]

now all I need is post this data to remote API,

As you see in the image, all props are fine except the uploaded file. What should I do?

nodejsAPI:

```
async (req, res) => {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  var params = {}
  form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
      Object.keys(fields).forEach(function(name) {
        params[name] = fields[name]
      });
      params['MyFile'] = files['MyFile']
      const result = await AdManagementService.createAdvertisement(params)
    });
    

}
```

createAdvertisement action:

```
const createAdvertisement = async ({
  Type,
  MyFile,
}) => {

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `/ad/upload-file?Type=${Type}`,
      {
        data:MyFile,//if this line removed, it works fine..
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      }
    )
    console.log(response)
    return response.data
  } catch (error) {
    return error
  }
}
```

it works fine if `data:MyFile` is removed, but I need send the file as well, what should I do?

It returns 400